# Modifying or creating a new autoinst encoding

Tags: font-encodings, otftotfm, autoinst, fontools

I am trying to modify an autoinst encoding. Ideally, I would like to patch it with a command line argument or the like so that the process could be easily reproducible. If that is unreasonable I would like to use a separate encoding.

I first tried modifying the original file, which worked, but will break with updates. Then I tried to create a duplicate with a file name suffix in the same dir, in hope that it would override the default, but this had no effect.

After creating the files, I ran:

```
mktexlsr
fmtutil --sys --all
updmap --sys
```

resulting in the structure:

```
/opt/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/fontools:
fontools_ly1.enc
fontools_ly1_CUSTOM.enc
fontools_ot1.enc
fontools_oml_CUSTOM.enc
fontools_t1.enc
fontools_ts1.enc
```

The next attempt was to create an encoding not provided by autoinst, e.g. with the first line like:

```
/otftotfmOMLEncoding [
```

and then adding `-encoding="OML,TS1,OT1,T1,LY1"` to the `autoinst` command line. This gives the error:

```
otftotfm: encoding 'oml' not found
```

What are my options?

Comment: You've called the file `fontools_oml_CUSTOM.enc` and it looks for `fontools_oml.enc`, I guess. But OML is a maths encoding which exists already. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: You ought not be adding or changing files under `texmf-dist`. Use either your LOCAL or your personal HOME tree.

Comment: @cfr I am trying to generate the math symbol font(s) from the existing glyphs in a commercial font.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `autoinst`'s manual page:

> ```
>    -encoding=encoding[,encoding]
> ```
>
> Generate the specified encoding(s) for the text fonts. The default is "OT1,T1,LY1".  For each encoding, a file `<encoding>.enc` (in all lowercase!)  should be somewhere where `otftotfm` can find it. Suitable encoding files for OT1, T1/TS1 and LY1 come with `autoinst`. (These files are called `fontools_ot1.enc` etc. to avoid name clashes with other packages; the "`fontools_`" prefix may be omitted.)

So if you request `-encoding="OML,TS1,OT1,T1,LY1"`, then the first encoding `autoinst` will look for needs a file named `oml.enc` or `fontools_oml.enc`. `fontools_oml_CUSTOM.enc` is not a suitable name.

However, `oml.enc` is certainly not suitable, because this file will suggest the file contains the official OML encoding. `fontools_oml.enc` would work, but you should use this only if your encoding really corresponds to the OML encoding.

However, it is not clear whether any of this is really helpful, as it isn't clear what you are trying to do. Some explanation of why you want to provide a custom encoding file here would make it easier for people to provide useful advice.

> **In any case, you ought NOT change or add files in the main TEXMF tree.** This tree is for your TeX distribution's use and is managed by a package manager. (Either `tlmgr` or your Linux distro's package manager.)

Instead, you should install modified copies of files under different names and additional files in either your personal TEXMF tree or your local tree.

```
kpsewhich -var TEXMFLOCAL
```

will tell you the location of the local tree and

```
kpsewhich -var TEXMFHOME
```

that of your personal tree.

Comment: Outside `/opt/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/fontools` I only had success *without* the filename prefix `fontools_`, but indeed success.

Comment: @svenper Did you try e.g. `$(kpsewhich -var TEXMFLOCAL)/fonts/enc/dvips/fontools`? (And remember to update the filename database.)

Comment: `ls $(kpsewhich -var TEXMFLOCAL)/fonts/enc/dvips/fontools` gives `fontools_oml.enc fontools_oms.enc` but after a `mktexlsr`, `autoinst` still complains that `encoding 'om{l,s}' not found`. Changing them to `oml.enc` and `oms.enc` and doing the same works in the same dir.

Comment: @svenper Maybe they just mean you can leave it out for the supplied encodings? Or maybe you have to say e.g. `fontools_oml` on the command line? It doesn't seem ideal, but I don't know the software well enough to guess their reasons.

Comment: I found it also looks for non-prefixed encodings in `./`, which is very useful for my purposes.